Trying to add google-maps-ios-utils with SPM but getting 'checksum' error [iOS]
After fetching 'GoogleMapsUtils' dependencies, it just shows this error:
checksum of downloaded artifact of binary target 'GoogleMapsUtils' (...) does not match checksum specified by the manifest (...)

Tried reseting, resolving, updating Package versions. Tried restarting mac, Xcode, deleted DerivedData, deleted caches from Library/Caches, deleted the project, fetched it again, looked everywhere in the web, and still can't find a solution to my problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
